# Sql SUM from 2 different tables

Tags: sql, sum

How can I add two different calculations to a sum.

I want to add up these 2.

This one...

```
SELECT SUM((Price) * (InvoiceTime)) 
FROM tblTime 
WHERE OwnerId = 13749
```

and this one...

```
SELECT SUM((Price) * (Amount)) 
FROM tblMaterial 
WHERE OwnerId = 13749
```

Comment: You should always tag your question with your dbms (MySQL or SQL Server or PostgreSQL or whatever), because the SQL dialects differ here and there.

Answer (score 2):

You can select the 2 records with `UNION ALL` and then use `SUM` to add them:

```
SELECT SUM(a.Sum1) FROM (
    SELECT SUM((Price) * (InvoiceTime)) as Sum1
    FROM tblTime 
    WHERE OwnerId = 13749
    UNION ALL
    SELECT SUM((Price) * (Amount)) 
    FROM tblMaterial 
    WHERE OwnerId = 13749
) a
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT SUM((Price) * (InvoiceTime)) AS TOTAL FROM tblTime WHERE OwnerId = 13749
UNION
SELECT SUM((Price) * (Amount)) AS TOTAL FROM tblMaterial WHERE OwnerId = 13749
```

I think this may work

Comment: `UNION ALL` in that case, otherwise if both calculations are give the same result, one of them will be eliminated.

Comment: Anyway this returns two records, not the sum of the two.

Comment: But how do I get them to become en grand total ?

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from
(
    SELECT SUM((Price) * (InvoiceTime)) as sum
    FROM tblTime 
    WHERE OwnerId = 13749
    union all
    SELECT SUM((Price) * (Amount)) 
    FROM tblMaterial 
    WHERE OwnerId = 13749
) tmp
```

Comment: You forgot to add the two sums. And sum is a reserved word; I wouldn't use it for an alias.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the prices in the two tables are different and you want to add the two quantities into one sum

SELECT SUM((t.Price) * (t.InvoiceTime)) + SUM((m.Price) * (m.Amount))
FROM tblTime t, 
     tblMaterial m
WHERE 
     t.OwnerId = 13749
and  t.OwnerId = m.OwnerId
group by t.ownerId

Note : You have not specified the database, syntax could vary a bit. What I have specified above works with Sybase.

Comment: What is perfect about this? It is plain wrong. With two matching records in table tblTime and five matching records in table tblMaterial for instance, the join results in ten records (2x5). So you'd get the tblMaterial sum two-fold and the tblTime sum five-fold. Moreover: 1. GROUP BY makes no sense, as you only select one OwnerId. 2. The comma-separated join syntax has been replaced in the SQL standard more than twenty years ago and should no longer be used. 3. If one table contains no record for 13749 you get no result.

Comment: Sorry, I am new at this

Comment: @Kristoffer... I do see the points made by Thorsten Kettner to be valid. The query which I provided will work only when you have one entry each in the tblMaterial & tblTime for a given OwnerId.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with dotnetom's UNION ALL solution. Just to give another option, you can simply select one record with the two sums added:

```
select
  coalesce
  ((
    SELECT SUM(Price * InvoiceTime) 
    FROM tblTime 
    WHERE OwnerId = 13749
  ), 0) +
  coalesce
  ((
    SELECT SUM(Price * Amount) 
    FROM tblMaterial 
    WHERE OwnerId = 13749
  ), 0);
```

COALESCE(something,0) gives you a zero when something is NULL. So you avoid adding NULL + some_value resulting in NULL instead of the desired some_value.

Some dbms require you to use a dummy table that holds one record. For Oracle for instance you would have to add `FROM DUAL` (right before the semicolon).

Here is yet another way: Build the two sum records, then cross join these so to get one result record and add the two sums.

```
select t.tsum + m.msum
from
(
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Price * InvoiceTime), 0) AS tsum
  FROM tblTime 
  WHERE OwnerId = 13749
) t
cross join
(
  SELECT COALESCE(SUM(Price * Amount), 0) AS msum
  FROM tblMaterial 
  WHERE OwnerId = 13749
) m;
```